# Custom comparator on specific property

Tags: javers

Is it possible to configure a custom comparator on a named property on class. I can configure a custom comparator on, for example, all BigDecimal instances, but I would like to use my comparator on specific property.

Comment: no, but it would be handy, think abou contribution to javers

Comment: Sure, will try to understand the internals of javers and sumbit a PR.

Comment: By the way, thanks for javers - it is really nice.

Comment: thanks , and javers really needs contributors